# Should the "opening work" of a context manager happen in __init__ or __enter__?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I found the [following example](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) of a Context Manager for a `File` object:

```py
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, method):
        self.file_obj = open(file_name, method)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file_obj
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.file_obj.close()
```

Here, the *work* done by the manager, that is actually opening the file, happens in the `__init__` method. However, in the accompanying text, they suggest that the file opening should happen in the `__enter__` call:

> Let’s talk about what happens under-the-hood.
>
> 1. The with statement stores the **exit** method of the File class.
> 2. It calls the **enter** method of the File class.
> 3. The **enter** method opens the file and returns it.
> 4. The opened file handle is passed to opened_file.
> 5. We write to the file using .write().
> 6. The with statement calls the stored **exit** method.
> 7. The **exit** method closes the file.

Which is the correct approach in general? It seems to be that the work undone by `__exit__` should happen in `__enter__`, not `__init__` since those are paired 1:1 by the context manager mechanism, but this example leaves me doubtful.

Comment: That's not the Python documentation. That's some rando's tips site.

Comment: I tend to agree with you.  The `__init__` statement should have just saved the arguments, and the actual work that needs to be undone should be done by `__enter__`.    But not all code is perfect.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/) is the Python documentation.

Comment: And directly contradicting what I said earlier. The documentation says that `__exit__` is called if `__enter__` returns without an error.   If the `open` fails, you don't want the `__exit__` called.  So perhaps the rule is that in `__init__` you put all the code such that if it errors, it makes no sense to call `__exit__`.

Comment: Murphy says that any advice or rule of thumb given here will be directly contradicted by the next usecase OP tries to solve with a context manager.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - ha! Not sure how I missed that, I've updated the text though of course now the discrepancy is less surprising.

Answer (score 6):

There is no general answer. It depends on what the work *is*. For example, for a file, opening happens in `__init__`, but for a lock, locking happens in `__enter__`.

One important thing to think about is, what should happen if the object is *not* used as a context manager, or not *immediately* used as a context manager? What should the object's state be after construction? Should relevant resources already be acquired at that point?

For a file, the answer is yes, the file should already be open, so opening happens in `__init__`. For a lock, the answer is no, the lock should not be locked, so locking goes in `__enter__`.

Another thing to consider is, should this object be usable as a context manager more than once? If entering a context manager twice should do a thing twice, that thing needs to happen in `__enter__`.

Comment: On the one hand, valuable tips (you're a high-quality rando in my experience :), on the other, this is a long-winded way of saying "opinion based".

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It's a long-winded way of saying "this needs to be decided on a case by case basis", not "this is a matter of opinion".

Comment: I would posit that any statements you make without a concrete usecase are a matter of meaningless opinion. "Too broad" might be the better canned response"

Comment: What is not clear to me is _why_ file happening opens in `__init__`? If it is `__exit__` that closes the file, then it seems to be that `__enter__` should open it, or else they will be paired incorrectly, or as you allude to: "the context manager can be used only once". Why would you ever want a context manager that can be used only once?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: A file object doesn't have to be used as a context manager. That's *usually* the best way to use a file, but not always. `__enter__` and `__exit__` look like they should be inverses, but quite often, it turns out that's not the most useful design.

Comment: As for context managers that can only be used once, *tons* of context managers can only be used once. Anything created with `contextlib.contextmanager`, for example. Making a context manager safely reusable is a bunch of extra work, and making it reentrantly reusable or simultaneously usable across threads is even more work. It often doesn't make sense at all - for example, what would happen if you try to reopen an open file?

Answer (score 0):

### Hereis a better example

> 

```
class TraceBlock:

    def message(self, arg):
        print('running ' + arg)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        print('starting with block')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is None:
            print('exited normally\n')
        else:
            print('raise an exception! ' + str(exc_type))
            return False # Propagate
```

#--------------------------

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with TraceBlock() as action:

        action.message('test 1')
        print('reached')
    
    with TraceBlock() as action:

        action.message('test 2')
        raise TypeError
        print('not reached')
```

If The **Exit**  returns False the exception will pass on to other handler, if it return True the exception would not go to others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).